# How can i achieve the same texture as Soft baked Pepperidge Farm cookies?

Tags: cookies

I have tried their Soft baked Nantucket and Captiva Dark Chocolate Brownie and i really like the texture of it.It's sticky (or chewy),you can almost fold it and it'll bend rather than break.I don't know if i call dense or not but in the inside, there's no evidence of any air pockets that come from creaming method at all.

I try to mimic it at home but can't achieve the same result. My cookies came out cakey and thick.
for more info, I used melted butter and high brown sugar ratio, 1 egg+1 yolk and i used AP flour.

Thank you

ps.http://sweets.seriouseats.com/2012/09/pepperidge-farm-cookies-slideshow.html#show-269994 here how it looks like.

Comment: Leave out any raising agent and add more egg.

Comment: whole egg or just yolk? Isn't egg white make it more cakey?

Comment: I haven't had this particular cookie so I can't say for sure, "undercooking" cookies less can often make them more gooey. I like to watch for when the edges of the cookie are cooked (like 1/2 to the center is cooked) and then take them out and leave them on the hot pan to cool. PS: Note to self, don't answer cookie questions when hungry.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really TRY to bake soft cookies, but in my experience the easiest way to get them is to use margarine or shortening instead of (or in addition to) butter, which is consistent with the package label. Additionally, putting them in an airtight container while they're still warm will have the effect of steaming them, which will result in a softer texture.

Comment: i'll try to put in some shortening next time.